# iphone - uiactivityindicatorview does not hide

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

i know this is a very common question, i read most of the questions asked in stackoverflow but still couldn't figure out how to remove the uiactivityindicatorview from the view.
please find below the code

```
@implementation FeedBackViewController
@synthesize m_activity,webView;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];


    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://equinox.library.pitt.edu/limesurvey/index.php?sid=87435&lang=en"]]];


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [m_activity release];
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [m_activity stopAnimating];
    [m_activity removeFromSuperview];
    m_activity = nil;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
NSLog(@"in webViewDidFinishLoad")    
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    m_activity.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: m_activity];
    [m_activity startAnimating];
}
```

the header file

```
@interface FeedBackViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;        
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *m_activity; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *m_activity;
```

Also, i have checked the box in the IB that says, hide when stopped. I put `NSLog(@"in webViewDidFinishLoad")` in the webViewFinishLoad method, seems like it does not hit that method for some reason.
and for

```
NSLog(@"m_activity = %@",m_activity);
```

in the viewDidLoad method, it gives a message as below in the console

```
> m_activity = <UIActivityIndicatorView:
> 0x4d3d920; frame = (150 79; 20 20);
> hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize
> = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x4d35ce0>>
```

Comment: Side note: you should call `release` on `m_activity` before setting it to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `webViewDidFinishLoad` function is probably not being called. It may happen if the web view fails to open the url. In any case, you should also implement `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method and stop the activity indicator there too.

-edit-

To receive events from UIWebView you need to set the controller as the UIWebView's delegate. Just implementing the UIWebViewDelegate is not sufficient. You can do this by updating `viewDidLoad` method as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 webView.delegate = self;
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://equinox.library.pitt.edu/limesurvey/index.php?sid=87435&lang=en"]]];
}
```

Comment: @murat...i added the method webView:didFailLoadWithError method..still the indicator is still hanging around

Comment: have you set the controller as the delegate of the UIWebView?

Comment: @murat...could you please elaborate on what you just said.i am new to iphone dev...

Comment: please see the question above..added more detail

Comment: I have edited my answer and added how you can set the delegate

Comment: that delegate thing worked perfectly and makes sense too..thanks murat

Answer (score 0):

You should add `NSLog(@"in webViewDidFinishLoad")` lines to your code and watch the console to see if the code hits those points. Since this is a very simple example, perhaps m_activity is not connected to the actual object? Try to see if you get an address or a null when you add this to the end of your viewDidLoad:

`NSLog(@"m_activity = %@",m_activity);`

Comment: the console displays an address for m_activity but it does not hit the webViewDidFinishLoad method... i just wrote NSLog(@"in webViewDidFinishLoad") in that method.. what could be the reason?